# centering body and big slider

Tags: css, centering, jquery-ui-slider, shopify

I've managed to uncenter my body while trying to position my slider in the background so that it is also centered and so that it remains centered even when the window is resized.

The site is live   if your browser allows to zoom out you can see that the site is centered but when you open it and the slider image  is too big it just aligns with the left edge of the window.

I am self-taught so maybe I have missed something or just need some guidance how to fix this. please HELP!

the css is here:

```
#billboardWrapper {height:600px;width:1800px; margin:-170px auto auto; position:relative; overflow:hidden;  }

#billboard {height:600px;width:1800px;position:relative;/*background:#1c1c1c;*/ background-position: 50% 0pt;}

#billboardPrev,
#billboardNext { display:block; text-indent:-9999px; position:absolute; left:40px; top:270px; width:30px; height:30px; cursor:pointer; background: url(arrows.png) no-repeat 0 0; z-index:99;}
#billboardNext {left:auto; right:40px; background-position:0 -92px; }

.slide {height:600px;width:1800px;display:none;  } 
.slide img {height:600px;  width:100%; background-position: 50% 0pt;  
.slideLeftLayout .slideTitle,.slideLeftLayout .slideText,.slideLeftLayout .slideLink {left:auto;}
.slideRightLayout .slideTitle,.slideRightLayout .slideText,.slideRightLayout .slideLink {right:50px;text-align:auto;}
```

the html is (copied with firebug as the html is shopify liquid)

```
<html>
<head>
<body id="welcome" class="index" data-twttr-rendered="true">
<div id="body">
<div id="utility-wrap">
<div id="header-wrap">
<div id="content-wrap">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//dk0684j3ynpoi.cloudfront.net/assets/client.js">
<div id="gatekeeper-content" class="">
<div id="body">
<div id="billboardWrapper">
<span id="billboardPrev">Previous</span>
<span id="billboardNext">Next</span>
<div id="billboard">
<div class="slide slideRightLayout" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2; opacity: 0; display: none; width: 1800px; height: 600px;">
<div class="slide slideRightLayout" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 3; opacity: 1; width: 1800px; height: 600px;">
<img alt="" src="http://static.shopify.com/s/files/1/0059/9612/t/10/assets/slideTwo.jpg?108526">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

![here is what it looks like zoomed out][2]
![with a narrow resolution the slider aligns with the left side of the window and shifts][3]
![this is what I am aiming at?!??][4]

Comment: I think you have to use position:relative instead of absolute

Comment: it's not working please share valid code
http://jsfiddle.net/98GWT/

Comment: @Rizwanabbasi JUST ADDED some js - is that what you are asking for?

Comment: no i have checked this code in jsfiddle.net when i click on run nothing changed mean please share you working code so that we know what's the problem you have..

Comment: @Rizwanabbasi I'm a complete beginner so I don't think I am able to set up that fiddle :-(

Comment: open jsfiddle.net and paste you html code in HTML Box and Css code in css box and then click on save button jsfiddle change your Browser URL just share This url here...

Answer (score 3):

Removing the `left:40px` from `#billboardPrev, #billboardNext` on style.css line 287 will make the previous icon visible inside the slider even though you zoom-out the browser.

Also your "Next" icon is not displaying. To display that change `background-position: 0 -41px;` on `#billboardNext` in style.css line 288.

Your slider image is too big. Thats why it is shifting when zoom-in and out.

**Solution:**

Instead of using that big image, split it into 2 imges.

Use the following image as your slider image:
[image: small slider image]

and for your `#gatekeeper-content` use the following background and CSS.

[image: slider background]

```
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

The slider image is cropped to 960px width. Also try to use `position:relative` on your codes.

Comment: thanks but can't figure out why the slider does not center even when the window is smaller than the slider itself.

Comment: Just because you are using really big image for that(1800 × 600). Keep in mind that the website standard width is 960px only

Comment: I want the overflow to be hidden despite the large width

Comment: Can you show a screenshot or image of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: My reputation is too low to add an image but here is what it looks like when zoomed out: http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t385/bikeechick/wide_res.png
here is what happens at regular ressolution: http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t385/bikeechick/narrow_res.png
and this is the goal: http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t385/bikeechick/goal.png

Comment: Put your image link on your question just as text.

Comment: Anytime! Would be grateful if you could return the favor and give a plus one to one of my questions, I'm suffering from a temporary question ban from receiving a few negative votes :(

Comment: @Libin I wish I could use your solution but the site will use many slides with varying color ... I need a css / positioning solution. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: I recommend you to use [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/). It is very easy to use.